# InstallShield 2015 registry condition issue

Tags: installshield

I want to check if VC++ 2010 redist is installed, if not I want to install it. The built in prereq from InstallShield does not work, so I am trying to create my own.

As a test I manually installed the VC++2010 redist, and this is the registry on the target machine:

[image]

Here's what my condition looks like:

[image]

To me it looks 100% correct, what exactly am I doing wrong? Clearly registry checking does work in InstallShield because other build in ones I'm using work fine.

Can you spot an obvious issue?

EDIT: The values:

[image]

EDIT 2: If I recreate the registry key structure and value like this, then it works:

[image]

So how can I get IS to check the WoW64 part of IS, I thought that is what the 64bit radio check was for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u are looking at wrong place in registry to check whether the VC++Redist is installed. 
For Redist 2015 im looking in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\
and for redist 2010 HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
+guid